# Migrating from JAXB 1.0 to JAXB 2.2.4

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

I am trying to migrate an application from an older version of jaxb to a recent version (2.2.4)

This is the difference in generation of enums.

Generated code from old version

```
public class Type {

    private final static java.util.Map valueMap = new java.util.HashMap();
    public final static java.lang.String _ABC_4 = com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.installHook("ABC-4");
    public final static com.company.proj.xml.sysTypes.Type ABC_4 = new com.company.proj.xml.sysTypes.Type (_ABC_4);
    public final static java.lang.String _ABC_10 = com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl.installHook("ABC-10");
    public final static com.company.proj.xml.sysTypes.Type ABC_10 = new com.company.proj.xml.sysTypes.Type (_ABC_10);
    private final java.lang.String lexicalValue;
    private final java.lang.String value;

// other code..

}
```

Newly Generated code

```
@XmlType(name = "Type")
@XmlEnum
public enum Type {

    @XmlEnumValue("ABC-4")
    ABC___4("ABC-4"),
    @XmlEnumValue("XTC-10")
    ABC___10("ABC-10");
    private final String value;

// some other code
}
```

The problem is the difference of names (ABC_4 and ABC___4) in the different versions. Is there a way to generate identical names? Also is there a way to generate the string members like _ABC_4 etc which is not generated in the newer version of jaxb. The problem is the huge volume of code changes that makes it nearly impossible to migrate the project.

Another difference is that previously jaxb used to generate an Interface and an Impl class file. Now, in the newer version, it only generates the class file.

I learnt that this is possible through

```
<jxb:bindings version="2.1"
              xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb">
  <jxb:globalBindings generateValueClass="false" />
</jxb:bindings>
```

http://jaxb.java.net/guide/Migrating_JAXB_1_0_applications_to_JAXB_2_x.html

Thanks for helping!